# Analog video surveillance camera motion detection feature

Tags: camera

For example Samsung SCB-2000PH [Specification PDF](http://www.surveillance-video.com/media/lanot/attachments/customimport/SCB-2000.pdf) has motion detection feature. For what purpose it is in analog camera? That camera does not have any output pins/connectors, that can trigger some output signal when motion is detected. And if I am correct, than coaxial cable can only transmit video signal (not any kind of motion signals). And in analog video surveillance system all motions is detected by video recording software/hardware. So, why analog video surveillance camera has motion detection feature and what i can do with that feature ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: I read manual. And question is not about how to use that motion detection, but why that exist in analog camera. IP camera can record video to sdcard - so there is point to have that feature. But analog camera does not have any storage - only think is that analog camera can display text "Motion detected"

Comment: Which is easier for the human eye to see while you're fast forwarding through a day's worth of footage? A little bit of motion in one corner, or a big **MOTION DETECTED** message that flashes across the screen?

Comment: @Majenko, yes and interested area is covered with MOTION DETECTED text. What a nice feature. Probably that text is transparent. But video recording software with I am working can show where motion is detected.

Comment: In that case the motion detection facility in this camera is of no interest to you whatsoever. It's not a facility you require, so why are you even bothering to complain about it? Not all facilities in all products are tailored exclusively to your personal needs. It's a need for some people, but not others. If it doesn't suit your needs, then don't use it, or choose a different camera that does have the facilities you need. Don't complain just because it has this extra optional facility that you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try reading the [manual](https://www.aseko.fi/_globalimg/ngj_liite/2433/Samsung_SCB_2000_Manual_ENG.pdf) - the answer is right there in black and white:

> This product has a feature that allows you to observe
>   movement of objects in 8 different areas on the screen,
>   and the words 'MOTION DETECTED' appear on the
>   screen when movement is detected.

Comment: The manual also states "Coaxial control", there are up-the-coax communications protocols in use in analogue CCTV so it's entirely possible the camera could communicate a movement alarm to the receiver.

Comment: I read about 8 zones motion detection before posting. But to use Coaxial control, guess I need a special hardware. And I am not sure if that motion events can be passed to video recording software/hardware (excluding text 'MOTION DETECTED').